# RSpec: Could not find generator rspec:install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I installed latest Rspec gem and dependences, but when I call `script/rails generate rspec:install`, I get this error: Could not find generator rspec:install.
  Whats wrong?

Ruby 1.9.2 and Rails 3.0.3

My bundle list:

```
Using rake (0.8.7) 
Using abstract (1.0.0) 
Using activesupport (3.0.3) 
Using builder (2.1.2) 
Using i18n (0.5.0) 
Using activemodel (3.0.3) 
Using erubis (2.6.6) 
Using rack (1.2.1) 
Using rack-mount (0.6.13) 
Using rack-test (0.5.7) 
Using tzinfo (0.3.24) 
Using actionpack (3.0.3) 
Using mime-types (1.16) 
Using polyglot (0.3.1) 
Using treetop (1.4.9) 
Using mail (2.2.14) 
Using actionmailer (3.0.3) 
Using arel (2.0.7) 
Using activerecord (3.0.3) 
Using activeresource (3.0.3) 
Using bundler (1.0.8) 
Using diff-lcs (1.1.2) 
Using mysql2 (0.2.6) 
Using nokogiri (1.4.4) 
Using thor (0.14.6) 
Using railties (3.0.3) 
Using rails (3.0.3) 
Using rspec-core (2.4.0) 
Using rspec-expectations (2.4.0) 
Using rspec-mocks (2.4.0) 
Using rspec (2.4.0) 
Using rspec-rails (2.4.1) 
Using webrat (0.7.3)
```

bundle:

```
  group :development, :test do
gem 'rspec-rails'
end
group :test do
gem 'rspec'
gem 'webrat'
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upgrade to Bundler 1.0.9: `gem install bundler`

It was released on 1/19/2011 and fixes a bug where any gems included in :development, :test, etc. groups weren't loaded properly in rails.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run it like this

```
rails g rspec:install RAILS_ENV="test"
```

Comment: $ rails g rspec:install RAILS_ENV="test" ->Could not find generator rspec:install.